# Java 6 and JaxB 2.1

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2, java-6

The original release of Java 6 came with JAXB 2, but I have been told that 'later' Java 6 releases ship with JAXB 2.1.

Does anyone know what the first version of Java 6 to ship with JAXB 2.1 was?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently Java 6 Update 4 was the first version to ship with JAXB 2.1 ([source](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2008/01/jaxws_21_and_ja.html)).

Answer (score 0):

JAXB gets periodically integrated into latest JDK releases,
so, using the latest JDK implies using the latest (stable) JAXB version.

I suppose a possible JAXB 3.0 wouldn't make it into JDK 6,
same as JAXB 2.0 hasn't made it into JDK 5.